# How to make a loop with two loop variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, etoolbox

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt


\begin{document}
Method 1: %by \docsvlist from etoolbox
% This does not work. How make it work?
\def\lst{}
\appto\lst{1in,1pt,}
\appto\lst{2in,2pt,}
\appto\lst{3in,3pt,}
% length with unit in is for rule width, length with unit pt is for rule height
\renewcommand{\do}[2]{\rule{#1}{#2}\\}
\docsvlist\lst
%----------------------------------------

\def\aaa{1,2,3,}
\foreach \x in \aaa{\x}
% The above \foreach works well thought there is an extra comma in the list of \aaa.

Method 2:\\ % by \foreach from tikz
\def\lst{}
\appto\lst{1in/1pt,}
\appto\lst{2in/2pt,}
\appto\lst{3in/3pt,}
\lst
% The following \foreach gives error. I think this is due to the last comma in \lst.
% So, how to solve this problem?
\foreach \x/\y in \lst{\rule{\x}{\y}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `etoolbox`s `\listadd` with a slightly different input syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\lst{}
\listadd\lst{{1in}{1pt}}
\listadd\lst{{2in}{2pt}}
\listadd\lst{{3in}{3pt}}

\renewcommand\do[1]{\rule#1\par}
\dolistloop{\lst}

\newcommand\handler[2]{\hspace{#1} \rule{1in}{#2}\par}
\renewcommand\do[1]{\handler#1\par}
\dolistloop{\lst}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @cgnieder! In this way(`\listadd`), how to see the content of \lst?

Comment: @lyl you can do `\show\lst` or `\texttt{\meaning\lst}` if you want to inspect the list

Comment: In my example, both arguments of \rule are next to each other, so `\listadd\lst{{1in}{1pt}}` put them together. However, in many cases, both arguments(or both loop variables) are seperated. For example `\hspace{#1} \rule{1in}{#2}`. How to achieve this by `etoolbox`?

Comment: @lyl see my edited answer

Comment: `\listeadd`\lst{{\dimexpr 2in-1in}{.5in}} \meaning\lst, why does the length given by`\dimexpr` not expanded by `listeadd`?

Comment: @lyl add `\the`: `\listeadd\lst{{\the\dimexpr 2in-1in\relax}{.5in}}`

Comment: Thank you for your solution by `\the`. But I still do not understand Why \list`e`add does not expand `\dimexpr`?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed the issue is the extra comma at the end of the last list item. You can see that also in the simple loop when you print a character after each list item, which will print an extra character for the final, empty list item. This will fail `\foreach` because the last empty item cannot be parsed properly.

The solution is easy: remove the final comma, or not add it in the first place. It would be useful to determine during list construction that you are at the last item and in that case add just the item without the comma. If this is difficult then as a workaround you can remove the comma using `\StrGobbleRight` from the `xstring` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt


\begin{document}
\def\aaa{1,2,3,}
\foreach \x in \aaa{\x a}
% The above \foreach works well thought there is an extra comma in the list of \aaa.

Method 2:\\ % by \foreach from tikz
\def\lst{}
\appto\lst{1in/1pt,}
\appto\lst{2in/2pt,}
\appto\lst{3in/3pt,}
% remove 1 character from the right and store the result back in `\lst`
\StrGobbleRight{\lst}{1}[\lst]
\lst\\
% The following \foreach gives error. I think this is due to the last comma in \lst.
% So, how to solve this problem?
\foreach \x/\y in \lst{\rule{\x}{\y}\\}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The `\lst` is constructed by `\appto` automatically, so a `comma` has to be added each time. Then, in programming, how to remove the last comma of `\lst`?

Comment: @lyl see edit to remove the comma automatically after constructing the list.

Comment: Many thanks for the method from `xstring`!

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to use the “naked” `\appto`, but to build your own list constructor, so you don't need to bother with commas.

```
\newcommand{\addtolist}[2]{%
  \ifdefvoid{#1}{\appto{#1}{#2}}{\appto{#1}{,#2}}%
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\addtolist}[2]{%
  \ifdefvoid{#1}{\appto{#1}{#2}}{\appto{#1}{,#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\addtolist\lst{1in/1pt}
\addtolist\lst{2in/2pt}
\addtolist\lst{3in/3pt}

\foreach \x/\y in \lst{\rule{\x}{\y}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want an implementation independent on `tikz` and `etoolbox`.

The `\lforeach` command takes as first argument the *name* of a list (no backslash) and as second mandatory argument the code to apply to each list element. In the middle an optional argument sets a *pattern* to which the list elements must comply. If this argument is missing, the generic `#1` is used.

Note that this is not executed in groups. It would be possible to allow nesting, but it becomes complicated for a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{mo+m}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \cs_set:Npn \__lyl_lforeach_do:w ##1 \q_stop { #3 }
   }
   {
    \cs_set:Npn \__lyl_lforeach_do:w #2 \q_stop { #3 }
   }
   \__lyl_lforeach_main:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l__lyl_lforeach_#1_clist }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:cn { l__lyl_lforeach_#1_clist } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lyl_lforeach_main:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:cN { l__lyl_lforeach_#1_clist } \__lyl_lforeach_do:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__lyl_lforeach_do:n { \__lyl_lforeach_do:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__lyl_lforeach_do:w {}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\newlist{lst}
\addtolist{lst}{1in/1pt}
\addtolist{lst}{2in/2pt, 3in/3pt}

\newlist{lsta}
\addtolist{lsta}{1in}
\addtolist{lsta}{2in, 3in}

\newlist{lstb}
\addtolist{lstb}{(1in;1pt)}
\addtolist{lstb}{(2in;2pt), (3in;3pt)}

\lforeach{lst}[#1/#2]{\rule{#1}{#2}\par}

\lforeach{lsta}{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}\par}

\lforeach{lstb}[(#1;#2)]{\rule{#1}{#2}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make your own commands for common structures; for example when the list items are of the form `<a>/<b>`, you can define

```
\newcommand{\lforeachslash}[2]{\lforeach{#1}[##1/##2]{#2}}
```

and

```
\lforeachslash{lst}{\rule{#1}{#2}\par}
```

would produce the same as `\lforeach{lst}[#1/#2]{\rule{#1}{#2}\par}`.

Comment: `the "naked" \appto`, what's the meaning, thank you@egreg.

Comment: @lyl The “basic” `\appto`.

Comment: Many thanks for this solution and the idea `\addtolist`!!

Comment: @lyl I also provided a solution with no need of `\x` and `\y`.

Answer (score 3):

When OpTeX is used then `\foreach` (with different syntax than from `tikz`) is ready to use:

```
\useOpTeX
\def\lst{}
\addto\lst{1in/1pt,}
\addto\lst{2in/2pt,}
\addto\lst{3in/3pt,}

\ea\foreach \lst \do#1/#2,{\hrule width#1 height#2 \medskip}

\end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\clistNew \lMyClist
\clistPutRight \lMyClist {{1in}{1pt}}
\clistPutRight \lMyClist {{2in}{2pt}}
\clistPutRight \lMyClist {{3in}{3pt}}

\NewDocumentCommand \DoMyClist {m} {%
  \clistVarMapInline #1 {%
    \rule ##1\par
  }%
}

\DoMyClist \lMyClist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Package `multido`, as many loop parameters as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\multido{\dimW=1in+1in,\dimH=1pt+1pt}{3}{%
    \rule{\dimW}{\dimH}\\
  }
\end{document}
```